# Trying to increment a TINYINT by 1 each iteration in a While loop in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have created a SQL table like in my code below. Everything seems to work fine except that `@icategories` always has the value `1` in the table even that I try to increment that value by 1 each loop.

Why doesn't this increment by 1 for each loop in the `table123` ?

```
SET @icategories = @icategories + 1
```

Thank you!

**EDITED:** SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table123] 
(
    [_DateTime] SMALLDATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE()) NOT NULL,
    [_DayNr] TINYINT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [_CategoryNbr] TINYINT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [_FeatureNbr] SMALLINT DEFAULT ((-1)) NOT NULL,
    [_Value] FLOAT (53) NULL,
    [_Bool] BIT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_table123] 
         PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([_DayNr] ASC, [_DateTime] ASC, [_CategoryNbr] ASC, [_FeatureNbr] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UC_table123] 
         UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([_FeatureNbr] ASC, [_DateTime] ASC),
    INDEX colstore_ix CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
);

--Now insert values to the table
DECLARE @i int = 0,
        @icategories TINYINT = 0,
        @features0 SMALLINT = 0,
        @features SMALLINT = 0,
        @nDate SMALLDATETIME = '2010-01-01 01:00:00',
        @Date SMALLDATETIME = '2010-01-01 01:00:00'

WHILE @i < 31
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 15;
    SET @nDate = DATEADD(minute, @i, @Date);
    SET @icategories = 0;

    
    WHILE @icategories < 2  /*2 _CategoryNbr */
    BEGIN
        SET @icategories = @icategories + 1
        SET @features0 = 0;

        WHILE @features0 < 2 /*2 _FeatureNbrfor each _CategoryNbr */
        BEGIN
            SET @features0 = @features0 + 1
            SET @features = @features + 1
            INSERT INTO table123
            VALUES (@nDate, datepart(dd, @nDate), @icategories, @features, 1.1995546859184512, 1);
        END    
    END    
END
```

**EDIT:**

The code above is now correct. The `CONSTRAINT [UC_table123]` must be in place to have a unique: `_DateTime` and `_FeatureNbr`.
I noticed that I had missed to Only increase the `_FeatureNbr`. So now the code seems to work fine then.

```
_DateTime, _DayNr, _CategoryNbr, _FeatureNbr, _Value, _Bool
2010-01-01 01:15:00 1   1   1   1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:15:00 1   1   2   1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:15:00 1   2   3   1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:15:00 1   2   4   1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:30:00 1   1   5   1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:30:00 1   1   6   1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:30:00 1   2   7   1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:30:00 1   2   8   1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:45:00 1   1   9   1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:45:00 1   1   10  1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:45:00 1   2   11  1,1995546859184512  True
2010-01-01 01:45:00 1   2   12  1,1995546859184512  True
```

Comment: @Aaron. I EDITED my post. See the image there. It is my first more complex SQL script. You were right in the comment below. I have switched place so the `@icategories` loop comes after the `@features` loop. But still I get the violation: `iolation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UC_table123'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table123'. The duplicate key value is (1, Jan  1 2010  1:30AM)` I should get a `_CategoryNbr` 2 for the last 2 rows but it is still 1 there?

Comment: @Aaron, I have edited my code/post again. The problem was that I should have let `_FeatureNbr` only increase. Not easy to understand, I know. You did remove the `CONSTRAINT [UC_table123]` in the fiddle which then must be in place. So I beleive my code now then works. Sorry for the error. If wanting to undo the minus on my post it would be appreciated as it is my first complicated SQL query and first post.

Comment: Yes I could understand that ofcourse. Now `@features` only increase all the time so it gets to `12`. That true, I had 71 from the beginning. This was/is just a test script to fill this testtable with values that I will use for more test queries. I will now later when I understood the problem create some variations to this script. The fundamental error was that the nested loops resulted in duplicate: `_DateTime and _FeatureNbr` but now I then found the problem there. I usually use C# so SQL code is a little bit new to me now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are setting `SET @features = 0;` in wrong place. You should use this line after the `@category` increment. I guess you should use this :

```
WHILE @i < 45000
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 15;
    SET @nDate = DATEADD(minute, @i, @Date);
    SET @icategories = 0;
    --SET @features = 0;

    WHILE @icategories < 22  /*22 _CategoryNbr */
    BEGIN
        SET @icategories = @icategories + 1
        SET @features = 0;
        
        WHILE @features < 71  /*71 _FeatureNbr for each _CategoryNbr*/
        BEGIN
            SET @features = @features + 1
            INSERT INTO table123
            VALUES (@nDate, datepart(dd, @nDate), @icategories, @features, 1.1995546859184512, 1);
        END    
    END    
END
```

Inner loop `WHILE @features < 71` is executing once inside the second `WHILE` because `@features` is always 71 after the first execution, until the second execution of the second `WHILE` and again `@icategories` becomes 1. Hopefully it is clear now?

Comment: Thanks, that line was in the wrong place actually. However the `SET @icategories = @icategories + 1` seems to be in the correct place? But this still then doesn't increament and just have the value `1` in the table for All the rows. I can't understand why that happens?

Comment: Because that is how you put the logic! Do you want to have `@icategories` incremented for all the rows?

Comment: @Aaron, Yes it was a long script. I edited the original post and just changed this line to this: `WHILE @i < 100`. Now it takes just a few seconds to run the query. I get this error: `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UC_table123'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table123'. The duplicate key value is (1, Jan  1 2010  1:15AM).` It seems by my logic that that Violation shouldn 't happen since I increament the `@nDate` in the main loop?

Comment: `@icategories` has 22 values(0-21) for Each date.